# Ubuntu cant install Audacity. gtk-2-themes": snap not found

Tags: 16.04, snap

When I try to install Audacity (using the Software App), I get the following error:

```
snapd operation finished with error cannot perform the following
tasks:
- Ensure prerequisites for "audacity" are available (cannot install prerequisite "gtk-2-themes": snap not found)
```

What does it mean? how can I solve it? Im on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour, the snap `audacity` installs just fine in my system.

But if you are not able to install Audacity as a snap, you can go with the `deb`-package which can be installed with

```
sudo apt install audacity
```

Please note that the version of the snap (2.3.3) is slightly newer than the version of the `deb`-package (2.1.2).